# Python39 and pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7, pymysql

I've just tried upgrading up to python3.9.5 from 3.7 and I'm encountering a strange behavior that I can't quite nail down. It involves pandas1.3 and pymysql1.1.0. The strange part is that the dataframes lengths' are the same, but the data is just not right in the 3.9 executed version.

I'd really like to move forward to python39 but I can't quite figure what the issue is here...

Now when I run:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as mysql
conn = connection = mysql.connect(host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                               user='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                               password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                               db='xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                               charset='utf8',
                               port=xxxxxxxxxxx,
                               cursorclass=mysql.cursors.DictCursor)

somesql = """SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;"""

df = pd.read_sql(somesql, conn)
```

I used to get in python37, and which should be the correct format:

```
foo bar baz
___________
 a   b   c
 x   y   z
```

Now with python39, I get data returned but the data for each column is the column name repeated over in each cell:

```
foo bar baz
___________
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to the version of MySQL connector.  The column names are repeated in each cell when using Python 3.9.5 with pandas 1.3 and pymysql 1.1.0. Use this command to check : **print("pandas version:", pd.__version__)
print("pymysql version:", mysql.__version__)**

Comment: @AchrafBenSalah when I checked the version using pip freeze for the 3.9 vers. it said I was using 1.1.0, but in my code it was using 1.0.2. I've upgraded and now I'm using pymysql1.4.6 and data is back! Please answer the question and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is connected to incompatible versions of modules.

Please use these commands to evaluate whether your versions of pandas and pymysql are compatible with Python 3.9.

```
print("pandas version:", pd.__version__) 
print("pymysql version:", mysql.__version__)
```